# Where do I find microsatellite instability annotation for TCGA data

Tags: cancer, tcga

I have searched through the [TCGA data portal](https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcga/tcgaDownload.jsp) but I was unable to find MSI annotation for TCGA Colon Adenocarcinoma (COAD) and Rectum Adenocarcinoma (READ) datasets.

I am searching for the annotation on samples, i.e. if a specific sample is annotated as MSI (microsatellite unstable) or MSS (microsatellite stable). In particular, I found [this](https://tcga-data.nci.nih.gov/tcga/tcgaDataType.jsp) page, and followed the path:

> Data Matrix & Bulk Download: Select 'Fragment Analysis Results' for Data Type

but with no results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the computational aspect of Bioinformatics. While questions on interdisciplinary subjects like bioinformatics are welcome, they **must focus on the biological part of the subject**.

Comment: @AMR No we have clearly agreed that any question on analysis or understanding of bioinformatics data is on-topic. Frubudu, can you please provide a link to these databases. Your question, as it is, is unclear.

Comment: I tried to provide links and to specify better what I am searching for. I am searching for a link to these databases, but if I can provide more information tell me.

Comment: And it really isn't hard to find out why the OP cannot get access to this information. It is controlled-access data and that requires special authorization to access as it has information that is unique to an individual. https://wiki.nci.nih.gov/display/TCGA/Open+Access+and+Controlled+Access+Data

Comment: Thanks. So I need authorization to access them. May you put it as an answer?